# Synonym request: [source-code-quality] is just [code-quality]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

tl;dr: Can we have [source-code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code-quality) synonymed to [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) please?

---

Facts:

- [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) 310 questions - Wiki:

  > Code quality is a measure of how well a set of code balances qualities of maintainability, performance, and style.
- [source-code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code-quality) 36 questions - Wiki:

  > Source Code quality is a measure of how well a set of code balances qualities of maintainability, performance, and style.
- Both - 8 questions

I could retag, it's just 36 questions, but still.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, since this was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), I went ahead and retagged everything (*in source-code-quality only*) myself.

About half the open questions need closure (and most of those were tool requests), so I voted to close them all. I hope the community will help me close them by [reviewing these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=code-quality)

Answer (score 11):

While something could/should be done with those tags - making a synonym is not the way to go here.

---

To clarify. Syn'ing those tags would only mask a potentially deeper issue that needs addressing. Are they needed, can one/both go the way of the dodo, could code-quality actually be indicative of migration to CR if not on-topic for SO etc...

@durron597's done the right thing here (kudos) and spent time going through them.

Comment: I am confused. Per my reading of quoted tag wikis, these are synonyms, aren't they?

Comment: I am also confused. This answer could use an explanation on why you feel that they should not be synonyms.

Comment: They have the exact same definition. When would you use one in favor of the other?

Comment: Wouldn't tag [tag:code-quality] be appropriate when combined with a *specific tool* such as [tag:resharper]? For example, I think there is the potential that at least some of [these ReSharper questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[resharper]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+%22code+quality%22) would benefit from having the [tag:code-quality] tag added. (That is, of course, for those questions that are considered in-scope for SO.)

Comment: @DavidRR Most of the ones that were tagged [tag:sonarqube] were on topic as well. However, one could argue that those two tags are sufficient and [tag:code-quality] is redundant.

Comment: @durron597  – A couple of reasons why I disagree. ***First***, the [about page for ReSharper](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/resharper/info) indicates that ReSharper is more than just a quality control tool. So, I can see questions focused strictly on the quality control aspects of ReSharper. ***Second***, suppose I wanted to do a query on both [tag:C#] and [tag:quality-control] to try to learn about tools that might apply. (I'm assuming that there may be those who have no prior knowledge of ReSharper or similar tools for C#. Or someone who may be looking for an alternative.)

Comment: @DavidRR You may know that I am not shy about burninating tags. I'm on the fence about [tag:code-quality], personally; I was just devil's advocating you.

Comment: @durron597 – While I do think that code-quality has potential for misuse, I also think it can offer value as I indicate in my comment above. [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) asks us to give a lot of thought as to [when to burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/243253). And what we're doing here is one of the key points made in Shog9's answer: "Raise the matter for discussion on meta." Which is what you did. :-) Glad we're having this dialog! (Although your original question  is about creating a synonym, *not* burnination.)