# Is this the end of [code-quality]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) is basically a honey-pot for overly broad questions, opinion based questions, or tool requests.

Any of the questions I came across which were not off-topic, weren't directly related to code-quality.

These questions included:

- questions where the author wanted quality code,
- questions about code analysis tools,
- questions about other things that may have been *loosely* related to code-quality (but not enough to justify the tag), or
- questions asking how to do something.

---

This tag has <sup><sub>(since last update)</sub></sup>:

- <s>355</s> <s>315</s> <s>272</s> <s>236</s> <s>185</s> [**0** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-quality%5D+is%3Aq),
- **78** followers,
- no tag wiki, and
- an overly ambiguous tag wiki excerpt.

---

### Clean-up phase complete

Check the revision history for examples of questions closed during the previous phase.

Thanks to everyone that helped with editing or voting during the previous phase of this burnination. Your help is much appreciated.

### Deletion phase complete

All of the closed questions that were eligible for deletion have now been deleted.

## Burninated!

The tag is now empty, a big thanks to everyone involved, now here's a picture of Trogdor the Burninator!

http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/165/8/f/Trogdor__The_Burninator_by_cammarin.png

Comment: >implying code quality was ever a thing

Comment: @BoltClock I've living a lie :(

Comment: Pity http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299574/synonym-request-source-code-quality-is-just-code-quality didn't quite finish the job here.

Comment: Thanks for the effort; I've put in as much time as I can right now but would like to see the project continue. I agree with your goal, but I'm skeptical of whether it can be achieved. Some places the tag is used are locked, which will require moderator input to resolve. Other posts are very popular and may be difficult to delete; editing to remove the tag is the only recourse there, but as weak as the tag is, it's hard to argue the tag doesn't belong on those posts.

Comment: Worse: I found [one post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly) which I agree shouldn't have been asked (opinion based) or answered, but which has a lot of answers, including one very useful one. :( I find myself ambivalent about handling such posts; I feel a bit like a vandal voting to close/delete even if the post is technically off-topic. I bet if I kept browsing, I'd find others of a similar nature.

Comment: @PeterDuniho time to ask a good question that makes justice for that good answer?

Comment: @Braiam: a useful answer to an off-topic question is still off-topic. I can't imagine a question, good or otherwise, that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow and yet still fit the answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well, blog post, wiki, etc. are other alternatives, no? ;)

Comment: @Peter I'm using [tag:code-metrics] where the question is asking about actual measurable things like cylcomatic complexity and such.

Comment: @Peter I edited that question to not only make it fit the answer better, but also remove the opinion based wording and the code-quality tag. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Looks better to me. Funny thing I hadn't noticed before: the [tag:code-quality] tag had actually been added by one of the reviewers that had voted to close the post in the first place. I guess in a way, that person did the post a favor, as it likely wouldn't have gotten any attention at all otherwise. :)

Comment: After all the questions are closed/deleted/migrated to [codereview.se], maybe we can remove [tag:code-quality] from SO main site.

Comment: @Peter: only 35 open questions left, I edited 154 questions and voted to close 116 questions during this burnination.

Comment: Why not declare [tag:code-quality] as synonym for [tag:coding-style], even though [tag:coding-style] is intrinsically even more opinion-based than [tag:code-quality].

Comment: @Alex Because of the problem that you already identified, [tag:coding-style] should be burned, so I would just be putting it off until I get around to that tag. Why do tomorrow, what you can do today?

Comment: @BoltClock would you mind unlocking the remaining question so that it can be deleted?

Comment: @BoltClock: or at least remove the tag. As the lock is for "historical significance", it's reasonable to preserve the question, as long as it's not interfering with the removal of a undesirable tag.

Comment: Well, we might burn another tag on that locked question while we are at it: [tag:outsourcing]. AFAICS, it only contains crap, and little even of that.

Answer (score 6):

A list of the remaining [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) posts that are not closed. Search:

[code-quality] closed:no https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-quality%5D+closed%3Ano

All the LQ questions containing the [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) are now closed. For useful questions having the tag [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality), the tag is removed and rephrased. There are still 100+ closed questions breathing which can be seen on [code quality tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) list. All of them are LQ and can be deleted.

After all those are deleted, the tag [code-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality) can be removed from main site.(?) If there are still some **useful** *off-topic* questions, those can be migrated by mods to [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Still there are 184 questions(_as of now_) remaining and most of them can be deleted and for some, the [tag:code-quality] can be removed. [Code-Quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-quality)

Comment: @Tushar good point edit the answer and add that man

Comment: Why not declare [tag:code-quality] as synonym for [tag:coding-style], even though [tag:coding-style] is intrinsically even more opinion-based than [tag:code-quality].

Comment: @AlexCohn I had nothing to do with the burnination, I was helping reviewers find the posts once it was decided, best ask under the question